Flutter Run Error: SocketException - No Route to Host (errno = 65) on iOS Device
My Logs:
Flutter crash report.
Please report a bug at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues.

## command

flutter run -d 00008140-00063CA81413001C

## exception

SocketException: SocketException: Send failed (OS Error: No route to host, errno = 65), address = 0.0.0.0, port = 5353

#0      _NativeSocket.send (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1275:34)`
#1      _RawDatagramSocket.send (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:2590:15)
#2      MDnsClient.lookup (package:multicast_dns/multicast_dns.dart:219:22)
#3      MDnsVmServiceDiscovery._pollingVmService (package:flutter_tools/src/mdns_discovery.dart:232:66)
`<asynchronous suspension>
#4      MDnsVmServiceDiscovery.firstMatchingVmService (package:flutter_tools/src/mdns_discovery.dart:188:56)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      MDnsVmServiceDiscovery.getVMServiceUriForLaunch (package:flutter_tools/src/mdns_discovery.dart:433:50)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      Future.any.onValue (dart:async/future.dart:628:5)
<asynchronous suspension>

## flutter doctor  - No problems 

How can I fix this error please help. It only happens on IOS devices and I connect my own phone and others' phones via internet and USB and I still get the same error.
